# How to iterate through list of dictionary, extract values and fill in another data dictionary in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary as below.

```
[
    {'name':['mallesh'],'email':['m@gmail.com']},
    {'name':['bhavik'],'ssn':['1000011']},
    {'name':['jagarini'],'email':['m@gmail.com'],'phone':['111111']},
    {'name':['mallesh'],'email':['m@gmail.com'],'phone':['1234556'],'ssn':['10000012']}
]
```

I would like to extract the information from these dictionary based on keys, hold on its information in another dictionary as.

```
xml_master_dict={'name':[],'email':[],'phone':[],'ssn':[]}
```

Here xml_master_dict should be filled in with the respective key information as below.

In a fist dictionary we have this:

```
{'name':['mallesh'],'email':['m@gmail.com']}
```

**In xml_master_dict** name and email keys only will be updated with the current value, if any of key is not existed in the dictionary it should be filled in with None. in this case phone and ssn will be None

Here is an expected output:

```
{
 'name':['mallesh','bhavik','jagarini','mallesh'],
 'email':['m@gmail.com',None,'m@gmail.com','m@gmail.com'],
 'phone':[None,None,'111111','1234556'],
 'ssn':[None,'1000011',None,'10000012'],
}
```

```
pd.DataFrame({
 'name':['mallesh','bhavik','jagarini','mallesh'],
 'email':['m@gmail.com',None,'m@gmail.com','m@gmail.com'],
 'phone':[None,None,'111111','1234556'],
 'ssn':[None,'1000011',None,'10000012'],
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function to get the first element of a dictionary value (or `None` if the key doesn't exist):

```py
def first_elem_of_value(record: dict, key: str):
    try:
        return record[key][0]
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

and then build the master dict with a single comprehension:

```py
xml_master_dict = {
    key: [
        first_elem_of_value(record, key)
        for record in data
    ]
    for key in ('name', 'email', 'phone', 'ssn')
}
```

```
>>> xml_master_dict
{'name': ['mallesh', 'bhavik', 'jagarini', 'mallesh'], 'email': ['m@gmail.com', None, 'm@gmail.com', 'm@gmail.com'], 'phone': [None, None, '111111', '1234556'], 'ssn': [None, '1000011', None, '10000012']}
```

Comment: Depending on your actual data, you might also consider modifying the function to catch `IndexError` in case the key exists but the list is empty, and `TypeError` in case the key exists but the value is not subscriptable.